# Mongoose - return only content of an array, and not its name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting such a JSON returned from my Mongoose query:

```
[{
    "messages": [{
        "body": "this is the body",
        "sender": "John",
        "_id": "56ffbabb9a984f0804e8b3a0"
    }, {
        "body": "message body",
        "sender": "Jake",
        "_id": "56ffc60c68a75ab835a7e097"
    }]
}]
```

And I would like to get this (only contents of an array, without its name):

```
[{
    "body": "this is the body",
    "sender": "John",
    "_id": "56ffbabb9a984f0804e8b3a0"
}, {
    "body": "message body",
    "sender": "Jake",
    "_id": "56ffc60c68a75ab835a7e097"
}]
```

Query now looks as follows:

```
var query = Messages.find({_id: id}).select('-_id -__v');

query.exec(function(err, messages){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

        res.json(messages);
      });
```

What should I change here to get the desired output?

Comment: Why is this such an issue? Sure, you can use `.aggregate()` to completely transform the data ( only `.aggregate()` or `.mapReduce()` actually do this ) but really, why should it be an issue? Just tranform the response you recieve. And `.select('-_id +messages') is a lot more direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
// change .find to .findOne to get just the one record you want
var query = Messages.findOne({_id: id}).select('-_id -__v');

query.exec(function(err, message){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
        // return just the .messages collection within the selected message
        res.json(message.messages);
      });
```

Comment: Read the comment above. "projection" ( which is what `.select()` does ) cannot do this. Anyone who really knows this knows this is true. Besides, this is what the OP says they did already.

Comment: Actually, this is a good idea, but it would be good to detail what you changed to make this work: changing `find` to `findOne` (as you're searching by `_id`) and then calling `res.json(message.messages)` to just return the `messages` array.

Comment: Good point, @JohnnyHK, I updated the answer to include those comments.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, I'm not sure you read my answer fully; I wasn't "doing this" with .select().

Comment: Not understanding the hostility. The only change I made to my answer was to add comments about what I did as JohnnyHK suggested.  If you look at the sample output from the OP, he was not looking for an aggregate, he was looking for the array member of the one message his query was going to return.  The select() is actually not needed at all in this case, I just left it b/c it didn't hurt anything here either.

Comment: As an aside, there's no reason to call my answer "a lie", especially if it's apparently doing what the OP wanted.